# What is $a_0+a_2+ \cdots+a_{20}$ if $(1-x+x^2)^{10}=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{20}x^{20}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

> $$(1-x+x^2)^{10}=a_0+a_1\cdot x +a_2\cdot x^2 + a_3\cdot x^3 + \cdots + a_{20}\cdot x^{20}$$
>
> $$\implies a_0 + a_2 +a_4 +a_6 + \cdots+ a_{18} + a_{20}=?$$

I know how to expand binomials of $(a+b)^n$ type, but this one has three terms.

I can think of $(1-x+x^2)^{10}$ as $\bigr((1-x)+x^2 \bigl)^{10}$ in order to make it look like $(a+b)^n$. But I think, it would almost be impossible to find each coefficient.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: **Hint** $ $ The sought sum is the *even part* of $\,f(x)\,$ eveluated at $\,x = 1.\,$ See my answer for details.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

As we are interested in the even terms only

set $x=1,-1$ in the given identity and add  to find the sum to be $$\dfrac{1+3^{10}}2$$

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183307/to-find-the-sum-frac-1n-sum-binom-n23r-x1r/3183321#3183321

Comment: So, odd terms cancel each other and even terms are counted twice, therefore we divide by two.

Comment: @EldarRahimli, See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051489/prove-that-sum-k-049-1k-binom992k-249/3051495#3051495

Answer (score 2):

[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25678/242) that like $\,e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin{x},\,$  any polynomial or power series can be very simply decomposed as a sum of its *even* and *odd* parts as follows

$$f(x) = f_0(x) + f_1(x),\ \ \ {\rm where}\ \ \ \overbrace{f_0(-x) = f_0(x)}^{\large \rm even},\ \ \overbrace{f_1(-x) = -f_1(x)}^{\large \rm odd}$$

$$f_0(x) = \frac{1}2 (f(x)+f(-x))= \color{#c00}{a_0 + a_2} x^{\large 2} \color{#c00}{+ a_4} x^{\large 4} \color{#c00}{+ \cdots}$$

$$f_1(x) = \frac{1}2 (f(x)-f(-x))= a_1 + a_3 x^{\large 3} + a_5 x^{\large 5} + \cdots$$

We seek $\,\color{#c00}{a_0 + a_2 + a_4 +\cdots} = f_0(1),\ $ which for $f(x)=(1-x+x^2)^{\large 10}\,$  is

$$\begin{align} f_0(1) &= \frac{1}2(f(1)+f(-1))\\[.3em]
&= \frac{1}2((1\!-\!1\!+\!1^2)^{\large 10} + (1\!-\!(-1)\!+\!(-1)^2)^{\large 10}\\[.3em]
&= \frac{1}2(1^{\large 10}\!+3^{\large 10})
\end{align}\qquad\ $$

**Remark** $ $ As explained in the linked post, such *bisections* of series generalize to *multisections*. We can use a primitive $n$'th root of unity to construct the $m$'th $n$-section = linear progression of $\,m\!+\!kn\,$ indexed terms in an analgous manner as above.